# Calling a method using JSF2 + ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf

I've seen a lot of examples online of code where a method is called with a "f:ajax" tag but the name of the method gets shortened in the tag when the method name starts with "get". I haven't been able to find the reason for this. Below is an example of what I mean.

For instance, in the xhtml file "sayWelcome" is called:

```
...
<h:commandButton value="Welcome Me">
    <f:ajax execute="name" render="output" />
</h:commandButton>
<h:outputText id="output" value="#{helloBean.sayWelcome}" />
...
```

but the method in the bean is called "getSayWelcome":

```
public String getSayWelcome(){
       return  name;
}
```

Why does the "get" get dropped from the method name in the "f:ajax" tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaBeansSpecification defines the naming convention for the properties adding the get and set before the functions that acts as properties, see this [article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/writing/properties.html) for more info.

The expression language that use JSF also complains the JavaBeans properties name convention you can check this in this [article](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnahu.html), refer to the Referring to Object Properties Using Value Expressions section.

So in conclusion when the EL (Expression language) finds a sentence as `<h:outputText id="output" value="#{helloBean.sayWelcome}" />` it will try to call a getter or the setter function for the sayWelcome property, it depends if it need to assign the value (setter) or get the value (getter).

Comment: Thank you @César-Loachamin, that's the info I was looking for.